# How do I make the image smaller and make sure that It will not go in next line

Tags: html, css

I want to reduce the size of these images, but could able to do so through CSS styling.
And all these images should be in same line. Ultimately I am going to make it Hover transition.

[I have these three images here, for which I want to reduce the size.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIc6m.png)

Code -

```
    <section id="Description" class="D">
  <div class="sub-description">
    <p>Hi, I'm My name here.</p>
    <p>
      As Software Engineer, I am a passionate Software Engineer, and I am
      skilled in HTML5, CSS3, JavaScript and React.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="conatiner">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="imgBox">
            <img src="img/HTML5_Logo.png">
        </div>
        <div>
            <h2>Image Titile</h2>
            <p>ABCDEFGH</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="imgBox">
            <img src="img/css3_Logo.png">
        </div>
        <div>
            <h2>Image Titile</h2>
            <p>ABCDEFGH</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="imgBox">
            <img src="img/Javascript_Logo.png">
        </div>
        <div>
            <h2>Image Titile</h2>
            <p>ABCDEFGH</p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

CSS -

```
    section {
  padding: 150px;
  margin: 0%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'montserrat', sans-serif;
}



.conatiner
{
    position: relative;
    size-adjust:unset;
    width: 1100px;
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.conatiner .box
{
    position: relative;
    width: 350px;
    height: 400px;
    overflow:visible;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
```

Comment: Reduce the `width` of `.box`. Done.

Comment: use flaot left or right

Comment: @tao, reducing the width in .box, makes these images overlap.

Comment: add `.box img { display: block; max-width: 100% }`

Comment: @YasserCHENIK, float not doing anything. in .box. sorry.

Comment: @tao, No effect.

Comment: Create a *runnable* [mcve] and I'll have a look. Use codesandbox.io or similar.

Comment: @tao, Thanks, Here is the Sandbox link., 
https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-roentgen-yys5y7?file=/index.html

Comment: why not use flexbox or set the max-width: to < 33.3%?

Comment: @Tex, I've updated your example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-architecture-5jg579?file=/index.html). You were not applying the style at all (you missed adding `<link>` tag. And I had to remove some styles. Is this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To place elements next to each other you should simply wrap them and use `display: flex` on the wrapping element. By default pictures will be displayed at their native size. To only let images use up the available width you can use `img { width: 100%; }`:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/2000">
    <h2>Image Titile</h2>
    <p>ABCDEFGH</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/2000">
    <h2>Image Titile</h2>
    <p>ABCDEFGH</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/2000">
    <h2>Image Titile</h2>
    <p>ABCDEFGH</p>
  </div>
</div>
```